# Is the level requirement for class unlocks only for the basic class?

Tags: disgaea

I've been looking at the Wiki and it says to unlock as Male Cosmic Hero i need a Level 100 Male Warrior, i am wondering if i can reincarnate my Male Warrior into a Male Centurion and still unlock the Male Cosmic Hero at Level 100 with him or if i have to stay as a Male Warrior until i unlock him

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unlike all future Disgaea games, it doesn't matter which Tier of the class your character is when unlocking new Tiers in Hour/Afternoon of Darkness. If the requirement is 100, any Male Warrior, regardless of Tier, that reaches level 100 will unlock that Tier. The benefit is that you don't *need* to reincarnate each step of the way, but if you do reincarnate, your reborn character's level still counts.

In Disgaea 2 (I believe) and onwards you would have to level the next lowest Tier to the level requirement to unlock successive Tiers. The restriction is never that you can only level up the most basic Tier.

Comment: the wiki does say that in Disgaea 2 for the Warrior Class exactly which tier if needed for instance, Warrior requires a level 10 Fighter, a Destroyer requires a level 20 Warrior, it just doesn't say that for Disgaea 1 and i was unsure if the information on the wiki was referring to Hour or Afternoon and if it might have been changed in Afternoon

Comment: @Memor-X it's the same in Afternoon (the version I played as well). They probably don't specify since the first Tier can also be taken as the generic name for all members of that class, not just tier 1 fighters, but it is a bit confusing.

Answer (score -1):

Nope, sorry kiddo, but everytime you reincarnate the needed level of your character to unlock the last tier is increased by an amount, so if you want to unlock the cosmic hero the first tier of that class needs to reach level 100, but if you reincarnate as a centurion the needed level rises by 25 or so, and on and on and on... EVEN IN THE FIRST GAMES OF THE SERIES!, Believe me i tried!